# why is my password shown in inspect element - network tab

Tags: php, password-encryption

I have a login page which has a text field and a password field. When I click the submit button, it sends data to a php file which makes sure the data is the same as the hash stored in the database but when I check the inspect element(F12) chrome, in the network tab, the username and the password are shown in plain text.

How can I avoid that?

Any advise about securing login pages will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't avoid that.

Comment: You can create a JS script to encrypt the password while it is being typed... but I don't think this represent a problem since you don't send the password as plain text trough the web (you should encrypt it before)

Answer (score 0):

Even when using an `<input>` of type `password` one could inspect it, and change its type to `text` to see the real password.

Although, this is not very important as long as you unset your users' session cookies every 10 minutes or so of inactivity and prevent them from saving password using their browser (using a dynamic name for login / password inputs should do the trick).

Comment: How can I prevent them from saving password using their browser? Can you give me an example. I have a session cookie that expires every 10 min..

Comment: use random names for your login and password fields.